# create external module for android application

Tags: java, android, layout, reflection, module

I need to design an app designed for android TV player which show ads created by the client on his web site account. Ads are designed with java with animation.
So my app need to download new "skins" regularly from the server
I've already tried with reflection but the app and the skins has common class  and I get this error :

```
"reflection Class resolved by unexpected DEX had used a different ; during pre-verification"
```

How can I achieve this ?